# How to compute Bonds volatility from Duration and DTS?

Tags: fixed-income

I recently came across article [From Ad Hoc Bond-Risk Measures to Variance–Covariance Forecasts](https://www.pm-research.com/content/iijfixinc/30/4/6) from De Jong and Fabozzi, where they show how to infer the variance (and covariance) of Corporate Bonds using their Duration and Duration Times Spread (DTS) properties.

They idea is to decompose the return of a corporate bond starting from the duration approximation:

$$R_{it} \cong -D_{it} \cdot \Delta y_{it}$$

Then, to split the change in yield $\Delta y_{it}$, in two components the interest rate and the spread:

$$R_{it} \cong -D_{it} \cdot \Delta I_{it} - D_{it} \cdot S_{it} \cdot \frac{\Delta S_{it}}{S_{it}}$$

This allows to express the volatility of the returns as a function of the change in interest rate and the relative change of spread:

$$
\text{Var}(R_{it}) = ( D_{it}, D_{it} \cdot S_{it}) \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
           \text{Var}(\Delta I_{it}) & \text{Cov}\left(\Delta I_{it}, \frac{\Delta S_{it}}{S_{it}}\right) \\
           \text{Cov}\left(\Delta I_{it}, \frac{\Delta S_{it}}{S_{it}}\right) & \text{Var}\left(\frac{\Delta S_{it}}{S_{it}}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
           D_{it} \\
           D_{it} \cdot S_{it}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then, they suggest to estimate this covariance matrix using indices (and splitting across different pockets of similar bonds), but I struggle to see how they proceed with their estimate and then how they test their approach.

Has anyone already used this technique and would be willing to share some numerical examples?

My ultimate goal would be to use this technique to perform a portfolio optimization, using the obtained covariances.

Thanks!